# Binding Phalcon event manager to dispatcher causes error

Tags: phalcon

I'm new to Phalcon and I'm trying to bind a listener to the dispatcher service.

This is the listener:

```
<?php

namespace Core\Listener;

use Phalcon\DI;
use Phalcon\Dispatcher;
use Phalcon\Events\Event;
use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin;

class DispatchListener extends Plugin
{

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_logger = new \Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File( 'logs/app.log' );
    }

    public function beforeDispatch ( Event $event ,  Dispatcher $dispatcher )
    {

       $this->_logger->info( 'dispatching' );

    }

    public function afterDispatch ( Event $event ,  Dispatcher $dispatcher )
    {

        $this->_logger->info( 'dispatched....' );

    }

}
```

Not much happening yet, just trying to set things up. In my bootstrap index.php I have:

```
$di = new \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

$di->set('dispatcher', function() use ($di) {

    //Obtain the standard eventsManager from the DI
    $eventsManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');

    //Instantiate the Security plugin
    $listener = new \Core\Listener\DispatchListener($di);

    //Listen for events produced in the dispatcher using the Security plugin
    $eventsManager->attach('dispatch', $listener);

    $dispatcher = $di->getShared( 'dispatcher' );
    //Bind the EventsManager to the Dispatcher
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

    return $dispatcher;
});
```

Now, when I open the website, nothing happens with the listener. No logging, nothing. I must be overlooking something obvious here, but I' can't see what.

Answer (score 1):

What looking at your code with a refrehed mind can do! Not only did I in my original question forgot to mention that I'm working on a modular project. I also forgot that my modules are where I setup the dispatcher! So moving the aforementioned code to my Module.php solved the issue. So, my Module.php now looks like:

```
<?php

namespace MyModule;

use Phalcon\Loader,
    Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher,
    Phalcon\Mvc\View,
    Phalcon\Mvc\ModuleDefinitionInterface;

class Module implements ModuleDefinitionInterface
{

    public function registerServices($di)
    {

        //Registering a dispatcher
        $di->set('dispatcher', function() use( $di ) {

            $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
            $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace('MyModule\Controller');

            /* add a listener */
            $eventsManager = $di->getShared('eventsManager');
            $listener = new \SomeModule\Listener\DispatchListener($di);
            $eventsManager->attach('dispatch', $listener);
            $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);

            return $dispatcher;
        });
    }
}
```

And that's it, my listener now works perfectly.